# How can I fix MySQL replication lag on Windows when slave_io and slave_sql are both running with 'copy to tmp table' in Slave_SQL_Running_State?

Tags: mysql, performance, replication, database-tuning

i have a master - slave replication setup on windows OS, everything was working fine until few hours ago, i restarted my slave, slave_io is running, slave_sql is running, no error in the show slave, yet my slave lagging behind my master. In the Slave_SQL_Running_State, i have a 'copy to tmp table' statement, this should not be an issue from the documentation i read. so why will my slave be behind my master by 55000 seconds. i do not have cpu or memory pressure

i have looked at task manager and i dont have cpu or memory pressure

Comment: Did you execute an `ALTER TABLE` against a large table on the source instance recently?

Comment: Restarting only adds to the length of time to finish.  55K seconds is most of a day.  Does `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` provide the query?

Comment: YES SO I HAVE AN AGENT_TRANLOG TABLE WITH OVER 22MILLION ROWS agent_tranlog add constraint FKsscilb4fng5feti59wde213re foreign key (agent) references agent (id).